# How to change file upload date in Amazon S3 using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I need to move some files (thousands) to Amazon S3 bucket, from where they will be displayed to the end-user by another application (instead of the current one).

Problem is, that these files have creation/upload date now (dates very between 2012 and 2017, when they were uploaded to current application), and when I move them they all start to be of the same date. That is a problem because when you look at the files in the new application, you don't understand the time hierarchy which is sometimes very important.

Is there any way I can modify upload date of a file(s) in S3?

Comment: I've tried to connect to S3 bucket as an attached disk to a linux machine, and modify the "modified date" in linux system. In linux is shows: "Jan  1  2012 test.pdf", but in Amazon still "Fri Mar 10 13:31". But it was a try.

Answer (score 12):

The **Last Modification Date** is generated by Amazon S3 and cannot be set via the API.

If dates and other information (eg `user`) are important to your application, you can store it as [metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) on the object. Then, retrieve the metadata when displaying dates, user, etc.

Comment: Just a heads up, you can't change the date or last-modified values on the metadata either. This is system-defined and locked for modification by the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can just copy over the same object and the timestamp will update.
This technique is also used to [prolong the expire of an object in a bucket with a lifecycle rule.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331748/updating-aws-s3-expiration-time)

Answer (score 1):

What I did was renaming the file to something else and then renaming it again to its original name.
As you cannot rename directly, you have to copy the file to a new name, and then copy it back to its original name. (and delete the auxiliary file, of course)
It is not optimal, but that's the solution when using AWS client. I hope one day AWS will have all function the FTP used to have.

Comment: I think this is sadly the only way to get this to work. When you're working with a massive amount of files it's a real chore but worth it in the end to have modified dates.

Comment: How does this work? Would the new file be the current date? (OP needs a range of past dates)

Comment: @dustytrash Yes, the new file will have the current timestamp.