# Preserve "last modified" when sync between AWS S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm syncing between buckets (copying all files from one bucket to another).

`aws s3 sync s3://SOURCE s3://DESTINATION`

When the `sync` is finished all objects (files) got the in the destination bucket got today value in **Last modified** column.

How I can `sync` between buckets preserving **Last modified** value ?

[image]

Comment: You can't. Store the date as custom object metadata if you need it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729819/2442804 Or use replication https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html instead of a manual `sync`.

Comment: @luk2302, in the above link, it was about to set up a date. I would like to **preserve** the original one. Also, that question was 6 years ago, I hope that something has changed since then. Can you share any example of yours approach ?

Comment: Nothing changed about this, no. And the point of the answer is *"The Last Modification Date is generated by Amazon S3 and cannot be set via the API."*, that applies to your situation exactly. `sync` is just a combination of list, get and put - and that `put` cannot change / set the date.

Comment: @luk2302, I've tried the *replication* from one bucket to another, the replication is applied only to **new objects**. All existing objects are not copied.

Comment: It supports existing objects as well: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/replicating-existing-objects-between-s3-buckets/

Comment: @luk2302, you are right it support exsiting objects as well. Would you like to write it in a answer, so I can accept it ? Or I can do it instead.